# Why my Ajax is never done?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to send a mail with PHP, but the data are in Jquery, so I use Ajax.

The mail is sent, but I have the alert("Fail") and I don't know why ^^
jqXHR.responseText is empty and textStatus = "error" ...

I get all the data of my forms like this :

```
// Récupération de TOUS les élements DES formulaires
var lesChamps = $(".frm_etape input[type='text'], .frm_etape input[checked], .frm_etape input[type='checkbox'], .frm_etape select, .frm_etape textarea");

// Message qui contiendra les données que l'on passera au script PHP
var message = "";

// On empêche les submit de s'afficher dans le mail
$(lesChamps).attr("type", "submit").replaceWith("\n\n");

// Parcours des champs des formulaires
$(lesChamps).each(function(){
    message += $(this).attr("name") + " : " + $(this).val() + "\n\n";
});

        /* Requête Ajax */
         $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  url: "traitement.php",
                  data: { message }
         })

            /* Si succès */
            .done(function() {
                $(".succes").animate().css("display", "block");
                alert("Ok");
                // On attends 3,5 secondes puis on rafraichi la page
                //setTimeout(function(){location.reload();}, 3500);
            })

            /* Si échec */
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert(jqXHR.responseText);
              alert("FAIL");
            });
```

And this is traitement.php :

```
mail("r.v@a.com", 'Nouveau devis', $_POST['message']);
```

The mail is correctly sent, but always have the alert("FAIL") ! And the responseText is an empty string

EDIT : In the fail() I wrote :

```
console.log(errorThrown.stack);
```

And this is the result : {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function, …}

I found the solution ! Just add an e.preventDefault(); before my code !

Comment: What is the value of `textStatus` ?

Comment: @Riddick What does your console say regarding the request? Fail because of what? What data is sending to the endpoint? Is the endpoint correct and not blocked?

Comment: alert(textStatus) = error

Comment: It might help if you looked at the `errorThrown` variable in your fail handler, also the Network tab of the browser's developer tools, and if you showed us a [MCVE] of the **PHP**.

Comment: I can't use the console, because just after alert the page are reloaded ^^

Comment: @Riddick — There is a button on the console to tell it to preserve data between page loads.

Comment: @Quentin which one ? I'm on Safari

Comment: @Riddick — Right click. "Keep Log on Navigation". https://www.evernote.com/l/AAPn5NS5GT5Brb5mqVTGkxEgpczHszI_udU

Comment: Or just remove code that refreshes the page.

Comment: errorThrown.message = undefinied

Comment: @Glubus I don't have that ! I think it's the default comportment when a form is submitted ..

Comment: Don't log errorThrown.message, do ` console.log(errorThrown)`

Comment: It's an empty string

Comment: echo something in the ajax page where the functioning ends like after the mail is done echo something or use `die('something')`

Comment: @Regolith Umm .. I don't understand ^^ In Ajax how can I echo something ? I will post my actual code

Comment: not in ajax but in your traitement.php where all the functioning is done then put `done(function(data) {` data inside your function and use `alert(data)` inside the success function

Comment: After the mail function I did : echo("Bonjour");
    die("Au revoir"); But the page is reloaded automatically